# A String in URLs Crashes Chrome on Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, browser, crash, url

My question may not belong to SuperUser; however, I have come across a URL that crashes (closes, to be precise) Chrome browser unexpectedly. Add **`%%30%30`**  to the end of any URL would instantly crash Chrome. In some cases the browser with all opened tabs crashes, so as Chrome, and others only the current tab.

#### How To Reproduce

Add **`%%30%30`** like `http://domain.com/%%30%30` **(Do NOT hover on this link)**
Hovering on the link, or pasting in address, and hitting enter would crashes Chrome.

decodeing `%%30%30` using [URL Decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) give us `%00`.

#### Example

`http://example.com/%%30%30`

So why does Chrome can't handle `%00` in `URL`s?

#### Edit

I am using Chrome `45.0.2454.93` on Windows 8 x86 (32-bit); I have tested it as well on Android 5.0.1 Chrome `45.0.2454.84`. It seems to have an effect on mobile as well.

Comment: Can't even mouse over the damn thing, instantly crashes the browser. Also this is a neat game which uses this bug: https://github.com/szhu/3030

Comment: @nixda, considering I have asked this before the linked question, that question is a duplicate of this question. ;) Thanks for the head up; I will read it